# What does `append()...` do in Go

Tags: go

I have this Go code

```
kithttp.NewServer(
    endpoints.AuthorizeUserEndpoint,
    decodeRequest,
    encodeResponse,
    append(options, httptransport.ServerBefore(opentracing.FromHTTPRequest(tracer, "calling HTTP POST /endpoint", logger)))...,
)
```

Could you explain me what does `append()...` do with `...` in the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The append built-in function appends elements to the end of a slice.

Read more in [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append).

The `...` is used in variadic functions (of which `append` is an example), to pass all of the elements of the preceding variable.

So given a variable `x := []int{1, 2, 3}`, the expression `foo(x...)` will pass it to a function as if you had called `foo(1, 2, 3)` in contrast to `foo(x)` which would equivalent to `foo([]int{1, 2, 3})`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `append` takes the `options` slice, appends additional options to it, returns new slice and then this merged slice is passed as separate arguments to `kithttp.NewServer` constructor thanks to `...`.